# parallelism in the browser

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

Am currently working on a project, were as the `change` event listener is fired, a content is updated in the browser.

```
 <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
       <input type="number" max="100" min="1" value="20" step="1" />
       <p>CHANGE THE SIZE OF THIS TEXT</p>
       <script>
        const input = document.querySelector("input");
        input.addEventListener("change", evt => {
            const p = document.querySelector("p");
            const { target } = evt;
            p.setAttribute("style", `font-size: ${target.value}px`);
        })
       </script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

The problem with this is that, let's say i take 3 seconds to change the value of the input element everything works fine, if i change the value of the input element very fast the effect does not show up in the `HTMLParagraphElement` ( it seems likes asynchronous event in the event loop executes concurrently ). So i thought of using `webworkers`  but in webworkers we are not allowed to use `DOMElement` or `DOMApis`. Is there any way to allow this operations to execute simultaneously ?

Comment: I can neither reproduce the problem nor do I understand how parallel operations could be a solution.

Comment: if parallel operation is not the solution , what might the best solution is ?. cos i tried all i know and nothing worked.  the problem can be reproduce, put the code in an html file and run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you meant is that when you hold down the up/down arrows inside the input box, the text isn't changing size while you hold the buttons down.

The issue actually doesn't have to do with concurrency but rather with the event that you chose to listen to. onChange only fires when the element loses focus (i.e. on mouse up in this case). Meanwhile, oninput fires immediately when the value changes. So in this situation you want to listen to the oninput event.

Here is how you would do that: https://codepen.io/rzrzrz/pen/GBgLYr

```
input.addEventListener("input", evt => { ... });
```